# How to enable or generate user action logs in magento 2.3?

Tags: logging, magento2

I am working on a magento 2.3 platform and i want to generate user action logs(not admin) for example - log in time, page view time, device used, platform used, geolocation, log out time. How can I generate these logs or enable the system to generate these logs (if already configured) . If they are generated , Where are they stored in magento 2.3?

I tried to look into documentation and search on all sites, but i am not getting anything related to this. All i get is Admin action data.!

I want user action logs to be generated and then will use those logs to analyse user behaviour and engagement through ELK stack!

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for either Google Analytics/GTM or some other tracking scripts. Looking into JavaScript tracking scripts from external platforms might be your best choice. But if you definitely want this in Magento I don't know of any existing functionality like this. You might try searching for existing extensions or you'll have to build one of your own to track these actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rain2o. I understood your point about using JavaScript. I was also looking for logs which are user specific, like a logged in user looks for some particular product , spends some time reading some blog, I want to know all that. Will that be possible?